# PowerBI - Trying to sort a one-to-many column by the many column in visualizations where it would always be one-to-one

Tags: one-to-many, powerbi, dax, columnsorting

I'm working with bus data where each record in the raw data records a bus reaching a stop and how many people got on or off the bus. The raw data also includes which route the bus is for every record, and by creating an `ID` of `[bus route] + [bus stop]`, I can then reference a manually maintained stop order table so that the order for the stop in the context of the route is available for sorting. E.g order for `stop100.route5` = 4; order for `stop100.route6` = 8 , etc.

Example of the same stop having a different order here:

[image: Table1]

The separate table for stop order I mentioned is set up like this (filtered to show different values for the same stop):

[image: Table2]

Now that I'm trying out PowerBI I'm hitting a bit of a roadblock. I can't sort the stop column by the stop order column, as there are multiple values for each stop depending on the route in question. I know that I can still use stop order and stop as row values and toggle the 'expand all' setting, but my ideal is to hide the stop order numbers, plus in drill-down situations to stop level, the stops will be sorted alphabetically rather than by order number.

For any experts I have a few avenues I thought might be viable workarounds with enough know-how:

Is there a way to hide portions of a field's values in visuals? This whole thing wouldn't be an issue if I could use the `stop.route` IDs in place of the stop name field, but I would want to hide the `.route` portion of the value.

Is there any long-winded way to create a one-to-one sorting that I can use to sort the stop column? Some sort of dynamic calculation that filters a one-to-many to a one-to-one, as every context I plan on using this, there will be only one possible order # for the stop.

Many thank yous to anyone with advice!

Comment: Can you share some example data of what your tables look like and how you want your visual to look? It's a bit difficult to understand exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hey there - my apologies, I edited the post with some pictures of the tables. Basically in the first link I want to use the Stop order value to dynamically sort reports where stop is the row header. It would always be for only one route, meaning that only one set of the 'to-many' values would apply.